# how do i make this button interact with a database

Tags: php

Basically I am making a website and it will have admins on it, but I want it so the admins can add other admins so I've got it that when an admin logs in it displays the usernames of everyone on the site, but I want a button next to the username that changes their admin role in the database currently the admin is either true or false, the script for my project is below. hopefully, someone could help me, as I can't seem to make it change that user most I've got is it to change the last user in the list but I have deleted that as it wasn't what I wanted.

```
<?PHP
include("auth.php");
require_once "config.php";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM accounts");

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css">
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
</style>


</head>
 <body>
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
</div>
<p>
    <a href="ResetPass.php" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Your Password</a>
    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
</p>





<?php 




if($_SESSION["IsAdmin"] == 1)
{

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>



<table id=Username_List>

<b><?php
        echo $row['username'];

    ?></b>
<a class="btn btn-danger">Toggle Admin</a>

</table>

<?php
}}
else{
?>

<span>Hello Customer</span>

<?php
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the role of the user based on this button?

Comment: Yes, So in the database i have a bool, 1 = Admin 0 = Non Admin, so when I click it i'd like to change the 0 to a 1

Comment: You can use Ajax with jquery or javascript action and send request to a file that toggles admin rule.

Comment: Hi The users are stored in the database under username and the role is stored as IsAdmin, and I am using mysqli

Comment: I dont know Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle user type in your database, you need to get the userid and the current role of the user. Then you have to send these information to a php script to toggle the user role in the database.

Suppose we have a php file called toggleUser.php, which receives userid and current role using get method, so your url will be like the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="toggleUser.php?userid=<?php echo $row['userid']?>&role=<?php echo $row['role']?>">Toggle Admin</a>
```

Create file toggleUser.php and add the following code:

```
<?php
    $userid = $_GET['userid'];
    $role   = $_GET['role'];

    $role = ($role==1)?0:1;
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "update accounts set  IsAdmin=? where username=?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $role,$userid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


    header("location:showusers.php");
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214134/discussion-on-answer-by-hardood-how-do-i-make-this-button-interact-with-a-databa).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually solve the problem using PHP too.

I assume that the 'username' field is unique. I modified some segments of your code, by putting the 'Toggle Admin' in a form which is being processed by the same file. Once the button is clicked, the code added to the PHP block is executed. The code receives the username and current role from the form, and then toggles 'IsAdmin' in the database accordingly.  Here is my solution:

```
<b><?php
        echo $row['username'];

    ?></b>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="{$row['username']}">
        <input type="hidden" name="role" value="{$row['IsAdmin']}">
        <input type="submit" name="toggle_admin" class="btn btn-danger" value="Toggle Admin">
    </form>
```

I also updated your PHP block as follows:

```
<?PHP
include("auth.php");
require_once "config.php";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM accounts");

// Execute this code if the 'Toggle Admin' button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['toggle_admin']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['role']) && !empty($_POST['role']))
    {
        // Retrieve necessary inputs
        $username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
        $role = htmlentities($_POST['role']);

        // Toggle Admin
        if ($role == 0)
        {
            // Set user to be admin if not currently admin
            $IsAdmin = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set user to be non admin if user is currently admin
            $IsAdmin = 0;
        }

        // Update the database accordingly.
        $perform_toggle_admin = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE accounts SET IsAdmin = '$IsAdmin' WHERE username = '$username'");
    }
}

?>
```

Hope that is helpful.